# How to use Opencv and python to follow certain points of an objet in video?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, motion-detection

I have the following problem: I need to follow the movement of certain points of a bird that runs in a video. I have the points marked on the Figure like this:

[image]

or:

### [image]

I have a code written on python that allows me to follow a point inside a squared region (the square center) that I can mark at the beginning of the execution. It is based on the tutorial:
https://www.learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/

I can have good results (https://vimeo.com/224475205). But I need more  than a squared selected around the bird. Now I need some way to follow the movment of individual points in the complate video by selecting them from the image.
Which are my better options or functions to perform that task?

Comment: if you even find the solution, please post its answer, i need this a lot too. thanks a lot.

Comment: You could try the [Lucas-Kanade](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html) optical flow algorithm. This algorithm works best with points that are corner. So you should try to avoid to track points located in an uniform area.

Comment: maybe TLD Tracker